# How to minimize vTaskDelay in FreeRTOS?

Tags: adc, esp32, sampling, freertos

I need to sample a signal with a sampling frequency in order to 2500 Hz. But, when i put any time in vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(time)) under 1 [ms], my programa start to bug. How can i fix this?
Note: The 1 [ms] is relationed to 1000 [Hz], in other words my system can only operate with a frequency under 1000 [Hz], at least between the execution of tasks.

Comment: Task delays are the wrong method to use for controlling a sampling period at that rate. I wouldn't even try to use a task delay for anything faster than about 100Hz. You should configure a timer to trigger the ADC to take a sample and then preferably use the ADC interrupt to fetch the sampled result.